# Where can I get additional bibliographic information for a given entry?

Tags: bibtex

I am writing for a conference, and in their sample TeX file, they use the reference like:

```
@article{kaye:puc,
  year =         2014,
  issn =         {1617-4909},
  journal =      {Personal and Ubiquitous Computing},
  volume =       18,
  number =       4,
  doi =          {10.1007/s00779-014-0773-4},
  title =        {Special issue on science fiction and ubiquitous
                  computing},
  url =          {http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00779-014-0773-4},
  publisher =    {Springer London},
  author =       {Kaye, Jofish and Dourish, Paul},
  pages =        {765-766},
  language =     {English}
}
```

I tried with Google Scholar and got BibTeX from Google Scholar:

```
@article{kaye2014special,
  title={Special issue on science fiction and ubiquitous computing},
  author={Kaye, Jofish and Dourish, Paul},
  journal={Personal and Ubiquitous Computing},
  volume={18},
  number={4},
  pages={765--766},
  year={2014},
  publisher={Springer-Verlag}
}
```

You can see that it is not the same, there is no DOI link in the BibTeX Google Scholar gave me.

So where can I get the bibliographic information for a reference document like the one above?

Comment: What do you mean 'where'? Sometimes (99.9% of the time in my field) you need to enter the information yourself.

Comment: Do you really need the information given in the four additional fields -- `doi`, `issn`, `language`, and `url`? You haven't told us which bibliography style you use; if it's one such as `plain`, the four extra fields will be ignored anyway.

Comment: Hi @jon, of course filling information manually is always possible, but I believe that there is a better way to do that.

Comment: Hi @Mico, yes they are required. That's a problem.

Comment: Please tell us which bibliography style the conference organizers require or, at least, recommend.

Comment: This sounds like `biblatex` where all fields are supported by the standard styles.

Comment: Hello, it is the conferent http://cscw.acm.org/2016/index.php

Answer (score 1):

I use the browser extension [Zotero](https://www.zotero.org) to export `.bib` files. It also has the handy feature of downloading and renaming a `.pdf` of the article for offline if it is available, as well as organizing references into folders, and lots of other time (sanity) saving features.

Output for OP article:

```
@article{kaye_special_2014,
    title = {Special {Issue} on {Science} {Fiction} and {Ubiquitous} {Computing}},
    volume = {18},
    issn = {1617-4909},
    url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00779-014-0773-4},
    doi = {10.1007/s00779-014-0773-4},
    number = {4},
    urldate = {2015-04-17},
    journal = {Personal Ubiquitous Comput.},
    author = {Kaye, Jofish and Dourish, Paul},
    month = apr,
    year = {2014},
    pages = {765--766}
}
```

Comment: Could you tell a little bit more how did you get the above output?

Comment: @TiếuThủy With Zotero installed: visit the paper on the publisher's website. Open the Zotero popup, and click the document shaped button in the navigation bar that it puts there. The data for the article will be saved, and then you can right-click to export the `.bib` file. You can export a folder, or your whole library, but `LaTeX` will only print the citations you select with `\cite{}`

Comment: @TiếuThủy if the answer satisfies the question, you should accept it :)